# OpenAL and Audio Unit clashing

Tags: ios, core-audio, openal, audiounit

I have an audio unit with a callback from the mix input. This works correctly and records fine. The moment I open another view that uses ObjectAL (OpenAL), going back to the ViewController that records from the mic input causes the following error when trying to restart the processingGraph.

```
AURemoteIO::Initialize failed: -10851 (enable 1, outf< 1 ch,  44100 Hz, Int16> inf< 1 ch,  44100 Hz, Int16>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenAL uses the RemoteIO Audio Unit, so you currently can't enable both APIs at the same time.  A small delay may also be required between ending using OpenAL and starting the RemoteIO Audio Unit to flush all the current audio buffers in flight.